# Suppress auto axis range in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have an `axis` with two `\addplot` commands inside in `pgfplots`.
Every `\addplot` command cause the axis limits to automatically re-arrange in order to show all the plotted data.
I would like to suppress this feature for the second `\addplot` command in order to stick with the axis range of the first `\addplot`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please give us the minimal code of your problem. We do not want to guess around and even less, to set up the problem for you. It would be best, if we can copy your code, fix it, and paste it back. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the option `update limits=false` to the `\addplot` options of the second plot.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what i was looking for.